# JSON to HTML conversion using jq

Tags: html, json, linux, jq, nested-lists

I have a JSON in the below format, I want to create an HTML file from it in the given format. Unfortunately I can only use 'jq' to achieve this due to some limitations. I am new to the world of shell script and this one is really bugging me. The alignment etc doesn't matters, the table should be populated in the desired format.

```
[
  {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
    "key3" : "value3",
    "key4":[
      {
        "key5" : "value5",
        "key6" : "value6"
      },
      {
        "key5" : "value7",
        "key6" : "value8"
      }
      ]
  },
  {
    "key1" : "value11",
    "key2" : "value12",
    "key3" : "value13",
    "key4":[
      {
        "key5" : "value15",
        "key6" : "value16"
      },
      {
        "key5" : "value17",
        "key6" : "value18"
      }
      ]
  }
]
```

[HTML should appear like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1uC3.jpg)

```
<p>Summary of JSON</p>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key1</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key2</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key3</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >value1</td>
<td >value2</td>
<td >value3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >value11</td>
<td >value12</td>
<td >value13</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>Details of value1</p>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key5</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key6</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>value5</td>
<td>value6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>value7</td>
<td>value8</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>Details of value11</p>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key5</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key6</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>value15</td>
<td>value16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>value17</td>
<td>value18</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Regarding the input, will the top-level records always have the same keys as one another? Will the secondary records always have the same fields as one another? Will the secondary records always only be under one tops-level record, or could they be under multiple top-level records? Last question: can it really only use jq, or can it use shell scripting (if so, which one), or other "standard" utilities (e.g. perl, awk, sed)?

Comment: @JoeCasadonte in key4 we have only 2 json objects, but in real it might be dynamic, but they will only have key5 and key6. Similarly in the main json array I gave only 2 objects but since its an array the size might be dynamic, though the keys always remain same. Regarding using other utilities unfortunately I cannot use anything other than jq. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't know how to print such structured output in jq -- I was hoping there could at least be a shell script wrapper around jq calls. I'm sure it could be done with just jq, concatenating strings together ad nauseam, but I've not investigated how to do something like that since I've never had such a strict limitation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a meat-and-potatoes solution that begins with some generic JSON-to-html filters:

#### Some generic to-html filters

```
def p($p): "<p>\($p)</p>";

# input: array of arrays
def row2html:
  reduce .[] as $value ("<tr>"; . + "<td>\($value)</td>") + "</tr>";

# with style
def row2html($style):
  reduce .[] as $value ("<tr>";
     . + "<td style=\($style)><strong>\($value)</strong></td>") + "</tr>";

# input: an array of arrays, the first being treated as a header row
def table2html($tablestyle; $headerstyle):
  "<table style=\($tablestyle)>",
  "<tbody>",
   (.[0] | row2html($headerstyle)),
   (.[1:][] | row2html),
  "</tbody>",
  "</table>" ;
```

#### JSON-to-JSON for the task at hand

```
# Input: an array of conformal objects
# Output: header array followed by arrays of values
def atomicKeys2arrays:
  # emit an array of atomic keys
  def atomicKeys: to_entries | map( select(.value|scalars) | .key);
  (.[0] | atomicKeys) as $keys
  | $keys,
    (.[] | [ .[$keys[]]]);
```

#### The task at hand

```
def tableStyle: "\"border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;\" border=\"1\"" ;
def headerStyle: "\"text-align: center;\"" ;

def table2html: table2html(tableStyle; headerStyle);

def task:
  p("Summary of JSON"),
  ( [atomicKeys2arrays]|table2html ),
  p("Details of value1"),
  ([.[0].key4 | atomicKeys2arrays] | table2html ), 
  p("Details of value11"),
  ([.[1].key4 | atomicKeys2arrays] | table2html ) ;

task
```

### Output:

```
<p>Summary of JSON</p>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr><td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key1</strong></td><td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key2</strong></td><td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key3</strong></td></tr>
<tr><td>value1</td><td>value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>
<tr><td>value11</td><td>value12</td><td>value13</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>Details of value1</p>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr><td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key5</strong></td><td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key6</strong></td></tr>
<tr><td>value5</td><td>value6</td></tr>
<tr><td>value7</td><td>value8</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>Details of value11</p>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr><td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key5</strong></td><td style="text-align: center;"><strong>key6</strong></td></tr>
<tr><td>value15</td><td>value16</td></tr>
<tr><td>value17</td><td>value18</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe check this, you can generate easily with JS
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_html.asp